# Buffer polygon inward by percentage of area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, geometry, arcgis-10.2

I would like to buffer a polygon inward by a percentage of its area, using the polygons below as an example.

[image]

How could I shrink each polygon inward resulting in a 35% reduction of area? I am using the term "reverse buffer" because I want the newly created polygons to have the same shape as the originals and be centered and within the originals, like the schematic below.

[image]

I am on ArcGIS 10.2 and have SA and ET Geotools.

Comment: A buffered polygon never has the same shape as the original unless the original was a perfect circle. So: do you want to *buffer* or do you want to *shrink* the polygons about their centers?

Comment: @whuber - I want to maintain the shape so I suppose I'd like to shrink about the center

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In QGIS, there is a [Buffer by Percentage plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BufferByPercentage/) that iteratively finds the buffer length required for resizing polygons to a specified percentage.

You can either specify a percentage that's applied to all features, or you can use a feature attribute to resize each feature by a different amount.

Here's an example of countries buffered to take up the area they would cover if they had the same population density as India:

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution to a slightly different problem.  However, if you were to modify `buffer_length` to rescale the polygons about their centers, rather than buffer them, it ought to do exactly what the O.P. asks for. (+1)