# Calculate population coverage?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, intersection, area, population

I am relatively new to QGIS.

I am looking at the percentage of an population that has geographical access to healthcare. 
Therefore I have one shapefile with village boundaries including population number of each village. 
Another shapefile is all Healthcare facilities in the area buffered with 5km zones. 
I now want to calculate the percentage of the village area that is covered by the Healthcare facility buffers and multiply this by the my population numbers.

I did manage to create an intersect shapefile of the two formal shapefiles that created correct new polygons of intersection per village. I now, however, do not know how to sum the areas (Area_1) of all these buffer polygons which are coded equally in the attributable table (under P_06_ID) and divide this by the total village area (AREA). And then multiply this number by the population (Population).

[image]

[image]

---

The command does indeed calculate the percentage of the population that overlaps with that specific polygon. However it still does not sum the different polygons.

[image: output after command]

So what I now want to do is to sum those numbers with the same parish ID automatically (I do have around 500 parishes). So in this example sum `PopPerc` from cell 699- 709.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you would have to create a new column and input the command to calculate what you are wanting. You could try the following:

`case when "DNAME_2006" IN ('MASINDI') 
THEN ("Area_1" / "AREA") * "Population"
END`

[image]

UPDATE:

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do a simple SUM using the Field Calculator. However, there are a couple of other methods you could use (which are practically the same):

- *Vector* > *Analysis Tools* > *Basic statistics*

First open the attribute table, select whatever fields you want calculated and open the *Basic statistics* function. Select your layer, check the **Use only selected features** option and set the target field (in your case, "PopPerc"). Click *OK* and you will get the statistics including the SUM value.

[image: Basic statistics]

- Install the *Statist* plugin

This is very similar to the above method except now you can toggle between windows which you couldn't do with the above method (you had to close the *Basic statistics* function to change the selected fields). Personally I prefer this method because of the fact that you can quickly toggle, select various fields and run it immediately. The same setup applies here with selecting the layers, fields etc.

[image: Statist plugin]

And you can get pretty graphs!